# Buttons in JavaScript prompt window don't work

Tags: javascript

I'm reading JavaScript for Kids by Nick Morgan.
I'm trying to make a Hangman game.
I typed this code:

```
var name = prompt("What's your name?");
console.log("Hello " + name);
```

in prompt.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My first HTML webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<p>My first webpage</p>
<script>
  var name = prompt("Whats your name?");
  console.log("Hi, " + name);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on prompt.html, this window appears:
[image]

But when I click Ok or Cancel, this window appears:
[image]

And there is no "Hi, Sergei" (if I click Ok) and no "Hi, null" (if I click Cancel).

But why?
I am doing everything according to the book.

But here it works:
[image]

[image]

Why it doesn't work, when I start the prompt.html?

Comment: You must open the console in order to see `console.log`s

Comment: Because you never show it on your page, you just display it on the console.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
<p>My first webpage</p>
    <script>
      var name = prompt("Whats your name?");
      console.log("Hi, " + name);
    </script>
```

type :

```
<p id="Name">My first webpage</p>
<script>
  var name = prompt("Whats your name?");
  const getElement= document.getElementById("Name");
  getElement.innerHTML ="Hi "+name;
</script>
```